# popup menu not launching new activity

Tags: android, android-activity, popup

My pop up menu displays with these options:

```
New Contact
Share 
Settings
```

When 'New Contact' is clicked it should open the activity Make_a_contact. But nothing happens - the pop up menu just closes down, like nothing is supposed to happen. Any ideas? They'd be much appreciated. The code I have at present is:

**In my Manifest:**

> ```
> <uses-sdk
>     android:minSdkVersion="11"
>     />
>
>
> <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS"/>
>
>
>
> <application
>     android:allowBackup="true"
>     android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
>     android:label="@string/app_name"
>     android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
>
>     <activity
>         android:name=".thisisatest"
>         android:label="@string/title_activity_thisisatest">
>
>         <intent-filter>
>             <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
>
>             <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
>         </intent-filter>
>     </activity>
>     <activity
>         android:name=".Make_a_contact"
>         android:label="@string/title_activity_make_a_contact" >
>     </activity>
> </application>
> ```

**In my thisisatest.java:**

```
    package com.example.chris.omgandroid;

import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.provider.ContactsContract;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuInflater;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.PopupMenu;
import android.widget.SimpleCursorAdapter;


public class thisisatest extends ListActivity {
    @Override
    public long getSelectedItemId() {
        return super.getSelectedItemId();
    }
@Override
public int getSelectedItemPosition() {
    return super.getSelectedItemPosition();
}

ListView lv;
Cursor cursorl;


@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_thisisatest, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.New_Contact) {

        Intent intent = new Intent(this, Make_a_contact.class);
        startActivity(intent);

        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

public void Show_Settings(View v){

    PopupMenu popup = new PopupMenu(this, v );
    MenuInflater inflater = popup.getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_thisisatest, popup.getMenu());
    popup.show();
}
}
```

My menu looks like:

```
   <menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    tools:context="com.example.chris.omgandroid.thisisatest">

<item
    android:id = "@+id/New_Contact"
    android:title = "New Contact"
/>

    <item
        android:id = "@+id/Share"
        android:title = "Share"
    />

    <item
        android:id = "@+id/Settings"
        android:title = "Settings"
    />
</menu>
```

**Make_a_contact class:**

```
package com.example.chris.omgandroid;

import android.app.Activity; 
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity; 
import android.os.Bundle; 
import android.view.Menu; 
import android.view.MenuItem;


public class Make_a_contact extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_make_a_contact);
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_make_a_contact, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

}

**Edit Note:** Thanks to Greg below I now know the problem is with `setOnMenuItemClickListener` But how do I implement this to get my popupmenu to work? I am obviously missing code somewhere. In thisisatest.java I have modified the `public void Show_Settings`nethod so it now reads:

```
   public void Show_Settings(View v){

        PopupMenu popup = new PopupMenu(this, v );
        MenuInflater inflater = popup.getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_thisisatest, popup.getMenu());

        PopupMenu.setOnMenuItemClickListener(new PopupMenu.OnMenuItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem item) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),item.toString(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                return true;
            }
        });
        popup.show();
    }
```

When I build the project I get the error:

```
Error:(91, 18) error: non-static method setOnMenuItemClickListener(OnMenuItemClickListener) cannot be referenced from a static context
```

Comment: post the `Make_a_contact` class and also change the name of your class, you should follow the `naming convention for class`

Comment: posted my Make_a_contact class. What's wrong with the name?

Comment: He is telling you not to use underscores in your activity names, which is true, but it wouldn't cause the problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set a click listener on the popup menu using `setOnMenuItemClickListener` and handle the click there.

The `onCreateOptionsMenu`/`onOptionsMenuSelected` calls are used for showing action bar items in your activity toolbar, completely different thing from your popup menu.

Comment: Thanks, but I have little knowledge of how to implement this, as I'm new to Android. If you could develop on what I have at present I'd be grateful. I've edited and added code to my original question.

Comment: No problem, you just need to reference your instance of the popup menu. Instead of `PopupMenu.setOnMenuItemClickListener(...)` it should be `popup.setOnMenuItemClickListener(...)`